# Photoshop: get slices via SDK and copy content

Tags: api, sdk, photoshop, cs3

I want to copy the **content of the current seleced slice** in my photoshop cs3 document to a new document using an own written script/plugin.

Currently, I do this manually: I select the slice, press ctrl+c (copy), create a new document and then I press ctrl+v (paste).

What I have so far is the automation plugin example 'MakeNew' that creates a new document:

```
static SPErr MakeNewDocument (void)
{
      SPErr error = kSPNoError;

      PIActionDescriptor descriptor = NULL;
      error = sPSActionDescriptor->Make (&descriptor);
      ...
}
```

Any Idea how I can access the current selected slice and copy the content to the new document?

Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to get the slices even via SDK in CS3.